# PHP login, is it secure?

Tags: php

I was hoping someone could take a look at my first PHP login script and give me some constructive criticism on what I may of done wrong and if it is actually secure. Thank you.

I wasn't sure if I had used the password rehash correctly.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
{
$username = null;
if (isset($_POST['username'])) $username = strip_tags(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = null;
if (isset($_POST['password'])) $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=?"; 
$get = $connect->prepare($sql); 
$get->execute(array(
    $username
)); // Execute the query
if ($get->rowCount() === 1)
    {
    $row = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Fetch the result
    $db_username = $row['username'];
    $db_password = $row['password'];
    if ((password_verify($password, $db_password)) && (strlen($username) >= 5) && (strlen($username) <= 10) && (strlen($password) >= 5) && (strlen($password) <= 12))
        {

        if (password_needs_rehash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
            {
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=?"; 
            $get = $connect->prepare($sql); // Use prepare to prevent SQL injection
            $sql = "UPDATE login SET password=? WHERE username=?";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array(
                $hash,
                $username
            ));
            }

        $_SESSION['auth'] = $db_username;
        session_regenerate_id(true);

        $sql = "UPDATE login SET last_login=?, ip=? WHERE username=?";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array(
            $dt,
            $ip,
            $username
            ));

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO LOG (username,lastlogin,ip) VALUES (:username,:lastlogin,:ip)";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($sql2);
        $statement->execute(array(':username'=>$username,
                              ':lastlogin'=>$dt,
                              ':ip'=>$ip
                              )); 

                    reloadPage();

        }

      else
        {
        $loginmsg = 'Wrong Username / Password';
        }
    }
  else
    {
    $loginmsg = 'Wrong Username / Password';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to answer the actual question, but I wanted to give you kudos for obviously trying to make your application secure and follow best practices. We get TONNES of questions with absolutely no security measures whatsoever here, and questions like yours is a welcome change.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['username'])) $username = strip_tags(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = null;
if (isset($_POST['password'])) $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));` wont work. need `{   }` with `if`

Comment: Why you are no hashing password and making one query to database with username and password??? You making very simple thing much complex

Comment: There is also no CSRF protection and captcha on this, It is def not a secure.

Comment: Why are you trimming and stripping the tags from the username and the password? With prepared statements and correctly outputting data to html it really shouldn't matter what I put in my username (perhaps...) and password (definitely). Note that a username requires validation when you set it but there is no need when you validate it.

Comment: @KirsSudh One-statement `if` blocks work just fine without brackets in PHP.

Comment: Better you use a good framework that gives you natural good practices in the documentation. Such as Symfony2 or Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No. 1 Flaw

```
$username = null;
if (isset($_POST['username'])) $username = strip_tags(trim($_POST['username']));
$password = null;
if (isset($_POST['password'])) $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));
```

Try

```
$username = null;
if (isset($_POST['username']))
{ 
    $username = strip_tags(trim($_POST['username']));
}
$password = null;
if (isset($_POST['password']))
{ 
    $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));
}
```

> No. 2 Flaw

Always use `algo contants` along with `password_hash()` for better usage.

```
 if (password_needs_rehash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
 {
      $cons = array('cost' => 12);
      $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $cons);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=?";
```

All others seems ok to me.

Comment: #1 is not a flaw, just "bad" syntax.

Comment: Thanks for everyones help. I have changed everything mentioned :)

Comment: Do I need to add the $cons to: if (password_needs_rehash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) as well or just to the $hash

Comment: Ah ok, I only ask because the example on the php manual has it on the if statement as well.